# How can I use a square wave to interleave 2 LEDs with an arduino?

Tags: arduino, led, pcb, camera, square

I have a PCB that drives a camera. I want to flash 2 LEDs in time with the camera's framerate using an Arduino.

After some examination I found a CLK pin on the PCB that I think might correspond to the framerate and it outputs a 32.76KHz square wave with a voltage of 3.5V Pk-Pk. I was thinking of a pseudocode that looks something like this:

```
%Initialize by finding a place in the signal to start (at the edge of the square wave) 

%Define variables  

%current state of the Square wave     
SquareWaveState = 0   
%previous state of the Square wave  
lastSquarewaveState = 0     

%Read in signal   
Squarewave = digitalRead(SquarewavePin);


%Find Edge    
if SquareWaveState (Does not equal) lastSquarewaveState  
if SquareWaveState == HIGH

%From this point in the signal, we can time the circuit according to the square wave    
       
Loop(          
Turn on LED1      
delay(15.262515us) (time the square wave is 'on')      
Turn off LED1      
delay(15.262515us) (time the square wave is 'off')      
Turn on LED2       
delay(15.262515us) (time the square wave is 'on')      
Turn off LED2        
delay(15.262515us) (time the square wave is 'off')       
)
```

I have several problems though. I am new to Arduino (and electronics in general). I have high quality LEDs but the timing is extremely fast and I know LEDs generally need time to turn on and off. Also the psuedocode is not very robust as it relies on hard coding timing directly. I would test it out but due to COVID our lab is taking a break. Does anyone have any suggestions on making this code more robust? Does it make sense that the CLK pin would drive the frames of a camera?

Comment: I don't see any reason to use an arduino here. This would be simple to do with no code at all.

Comment: I want to use the Arduino because LED1 and LED2 cannot be on at the same time. I assume if I just connect the clock directly to the two LEDs they would flash in tandem with the voltage increase. (Sorry if I am missing anything, I am a newbie :))

Comment: I don't see how you can guarantee sync of the lights with an arduino. Is this CLK pin coming from the PCB that runs the camera? Seems like you should trigger off of that CLK pin only - maybe just use a couple of D flipflops to have the LED's swap back and forth at each clock pulse

Comment: Yes, the CLK pin is coming from the PCB that runs the camera. The D-flip-flops make sense. I guess it might be easier to do this all on a breadboard. Thank you!

Comment: @Synaptic_Sparks Well, hooking them up directly won't work, no. Connecting them up intelligently you can have one turn on when the clock is high and one when the clock is low, but if you want them to alternate every clock cycle you can use a flip-flop made from a few transistors, or a simple IC.

Comment: You are asking for femtosecond resolution in the Arduino delays. That is just never going to happen, and the Arduino will eventually be out of sync with the camera. An Arduino is the wrong approach here.